# Query with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I am running a query:

```
select course.course,iars.id, 
        students.rollno,
        students.name as name,
        teachers.name as tname, 
        students.studentid, 
        attndata.studentid ,sum(attndata.obt) as obt
        sum(attndata.benefits) as ben , (sum(attndata.max)) as abc  
from  groups, students
        left join iars 
           on iars.id
        left join str 
           on str.studentid=students.studentid
        left join course
           on course.c_id=students.course
        left join teachers
           on teachers.id=iars.teacherid
        join sgm 
           on sgm.studentid=students.studentid
        left join attndata 
           on attndata.studentid=students.studentid and iars.id=attndata.iarsid
        left join sps 
           on sps.studentid=students.studentid and iars.paperid=sps.paperid
        left join semdef 
           on semdef.semesterid=str.semesterid 
        where students.course='1' 
           and students.status='regular' 
           and sps.paperid='5'
           and  iars.courseid=students.course 
           and iars.semester=str.semesterid 
           and semdef.month=9
           and iars.paperid='5'
           and str.semesterid='1'
           and str.sessionid='12'
           and groups.id=sgm.groupid 
        group by sps.studentid,
           teachers.id,
           semdef.month
        order by
           students.name
```

In this query whenever I am having left join on `semdef.id=attndata.mon`, I am getting zero result when the value of `semdef.id=null` but I want all the results, irrespective of `semdef`, but I want to use it. As in it should fetch result, if the values are null. Can you please help it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because your where clause is saying

```
and semdef.month=9
```

and you probably want

```
and (semdef.month=9 OR semdef.id IS NULL)
```

or something similar.

Comment: Okay, if i have some value as null, how can i show them as zero from the query itself?

Comment: try "ISNULL(yourfield,0)" instead of just "yourfield"

Answer (score 1):

It's because your where clause has statements relating to the semdef table. Add these to the join clause as putting these in the where is implying an inner join.

Eg:

```
Left join semdef on xxx and semdef.id = attndata.min
```